# Bootstrap button is not working, Tried cursor pointer and (click), still didn't work

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Angular and Bootstrap, but I found a code from a website but when I put it in my project, the button did not work.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let P of products">
        <div class="card" *ngIf="P.Category == selectedCategory">
          <img class="card-img" src="{{P.Img}}" alt="Vans">
          <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-end">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{P.Name}}</h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Serial No. {{P.SerialNumber}}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{P.Description}}</p>
            <div class="buy d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="price text-success"><h5 class="mt-4">${{P.Price}}</h5></div>
               <button type="button"  (click)="addToCart(P)" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 curs"> Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the css code

```
body {
    padding: 2rem 0rem;
  }
  
  .like {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a function called addToCart?

Comment: What do you mean by: the button doesn't work? Can you be more specific? In your button class you have "curs" what's that? I've never seen that on bootstrap, is it a custom class in your css?

Comment: Thank you so much guys, but I solved it, I just deleted the {card-img-overlay;} from the class.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

did you insert the bootstrap CDN link for CSS? if not then paste this under your css file inside the head section

```html
 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Yes I do, but I solved it, Thank you very much, I just deleted the {card-img-overlay;} from the class.
Thank you